# Migrating from SimpleFormController based implementation in Spring 2.5 to annotation based Controllers in Spring 4

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, data-binding, migration

I am facing an issue while migrating from spring 2.5 to 4. Earlier my code was using implementations of SpringForController and since they are deprecated, I need to switch to annotation based controller configuration. These are some of the overridden methods used in spring 2.5 :

```
protected Map referenceData(HttpServletRequest request, Object command,
        Errors errors) throws Exception {
    //custom code
}

protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors)
        throws Exception {
    MyObject obj = (MyObject) command;
    // custom code
}

protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request,
        ServletRequestDataBinder binder) {
    super.initBinder(request, binder);
    //custom code
}

protected void onBindAndValidate(HttpServletRequest request,
        Object command, BindException error) throws Exception {
    super.onBindAndValidate(request, command, error);
    // custom code
}

protected Object formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request)
        throws Exception {
    //custom code
}
```

I have annotated the referenceData method using getMapping and tweaked the code for it to render a form. The same goes for InitBinder method as well. As for the post method(onSubmit method), I have done the following :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "myCustomUrl", method = RequestMethod.POST)
protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute("command") 
        EmployeeForm employeeForm)
        throws Exception {
    //custom code
}
```

The issue I am facing is with the binding of data. The object EmployeeForm contains a lot more fields that doesn't have corresponding fields in the form being submitted. And because of this those values are being set to the default values(null if it is an object and 0 if it is a number). These fields in EmployeeForm may be populated through separate requests. But when I submit the above form, all the fields in EmployeeForm that are not in the form request will be taken as null(or their default values depending on the type of data). This was handled in spring 2.5 using the formBackingObject by which the fields in the command Object is bound to. Is there a way to do the same than getting the respective entity from the database and setting each field submitted by the form manually in to the entity?

As for the logic written in onBindAndValidate, should I use annotations with custom validator in the model class for validating or is there any other way to make it work as there are many custom code in it other than that deals with validation.